# scrape web page and write to CSV using Python

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape a web page at my company and write the result to a CSV file.

I am able to get at the data I want with this code:

```py
page = requests.get('https://wiki.us.cworld.company.com/display/6TO/AWS+Accounts', auth=('tdunphy', 'secret!'))
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
html = list(soup.children)[1]
all_rows = soup.find_all('tr')
row_count = 0
for row in all_rows:
    row_count += 1
    if row_count == 1:
        continue
    print(row.get_text())
```

But the resulting data is run together and barely decipherable:

```
company-govcloud-ab-mc-stage-adminkpmg-us-aws-adv-ab-mc-govcloud-admin-stageCommercial AccountAdvisory12345678901NoIslandhttps://company-govcloud-ab-mc-stage-admin.signin.aws.amazon.com/consoleKarel Somebody23452126676371Console, Access Key
company-govcloud-ab-mc-stagekpmg-us-aws-adv-ab-mc-govcloud-stageGov AccountAdvisory12324546562NoIslandhttps://company-govcloud-ab-mc-stage.signin.amazonaws-us-gov.com/consoleKarel Somebody123213123131Console, Access Key
company-cob(Decommissioned 03/28/2019)company-COB COB, Client OnboardingAdvisory21234546789812NoIslandhttps://company-cob.signin.aws.amazon.com/console/Laurence LorcaPending DecommissionConsole, Access Key
```

I want the resulting CSV to have the following headers:

```py
['Company Account Name', 'AWS Account Name', 'Description', 'LOB', 'AWS Account Number', 'CIDR Block', 'Connected to Montvale', 'Peninsula or Island', 'URL', 'Owner', 'Engagement Code', 'CloudOps Access Type']
```

On the original web page the data is in an HTML table, and the results are legible:

```
company-govcloud-ab-mc-stage-admin  company-us-aws-adv-ab-mc-govcloud-admin-stage   Commercial Account  Advisory    12345667890101  No  Island  https://company-govcloud-ab-mc-stage-admin.signin.aws.amazon.com/console    Karel Somebody  123456789101    Console, Access Key
```

Here is some sample HTML from the data that I'm extracting:

```
<tr><td class="confluenceTd">company-master</td><td class="confluenceTd">us-ktawsmasacct</td><td class="confluenceTd">Master Account</td><td class="confluenceTd">BPG</td><td class="confluenceTd"><span style="text-decoration: none;">123456789101</span></td><td colspan="1" class="confluenceTd"><br/></td><td class="confluenceTd">No</td><td class="confluenceTd">N/A - no cloud resources</td><td class="confluenceTd"><a href="https://us-ktech-aws-master-acct.signin.aws.amazon.com/console" class="external-link" rel="nofollow">https://us-ktech-aws-master-acct.signin.aws.amazon.com/console</a></td><td class="confluenceTd">Rahul Arya</td><td class="confluenceTd"> 245612345678</td><td class="confluenceTd">Console,   Access Key</td></tr><tr><td class="confluenceTd">company-transit-hub1</td><td class="confluenceTd">us-ktawsth1acct</td><td class="confluenceTd">Transit Hub</td><td class="confluenceTd">BPG</td><td class="confluenceTd"><span style="text-decoration: none;">303779310401</span></td><td colspan="1" class="confluenceTd"><span style="color: rgb(0,0,0);">10.47.0.0/24</span></td><td class="confluenceTd">No</td><td class="confluenceTd">Peninsula</td><td class="confluenceTd"><a href="https://company-transit-hub1.signin.aws.amazon.com/console" class="external-link" rel="nofollow">https://company-transit-hub1.signin.aws.amazon.com/console</a></td><td class="confluenceTd">Rahul Arya</td><td class="confluenceTd"> 245612345678</td><td class="confluenceTd">Console,   Access Key</td></tr>

<tr><td colspan="1" class="confluenceTd">company-transit-hub3 (lab)</td><td colspan="1" class="confluenceTd"><span style="color: rgb(68,68,68);text-decoration: none;">us-dbawsth3acct</span></td><td colspan="1" class="confluenceTd">Transit Hub</td><td colspan="1" class="confluenceTd">BPG</td><td colspan="1" class="confluenceTd"><span style="color: rgb(68,68,68);text-decoration: none;">1098765432101</span> </td><td colspan="1" class="confluenceTd"><span style="color: rgb(0,0,0);">10.0.0.0/24</span></td><td colspan="1" class="confluenceTd">No</td><td colspan="1" class="confluenceTd">Island</td><td colspan="1" class="confluenceTd"> <a href="https://company-transithub3-lab.signin.aws.amazon.com/console" class="external-link" rel="nofollow">https://company-transithub3-lab.signin.aws.amazon.com/console</a></td><td colspan="1" class="confluenceTd">Rahul Arya </td><td colspan="1" class="confluenceTd"> </td><td colspan="1" class="confluenceTd">Console, Access Key</td></tr>

<tr><td class="confluenceTd">company-security</td><td class="confluenceTd"><span style="color: rgb(68,68,68);text-decoration: none;">us-ktawssecacct</span></td><td class="confluenceTd">Security</td><td class="confluenceTd">BPG</td><td class="confluenceTd">254312345691</td><td colspan="1" class="confluenceTd"><br/></td><td class="confluenceTd">No</td><td class="confluenceTd"><span>connected through hub1</span></td><td class="confluenceTd"><a href="https://us-ktawssecacct.signin.aws.amazon.com/console" class="external-link" rel="nofollow">https://us-ktawssecacct.signin.aws.amazon.com/console</a></td><td class="confluenceTd">Rahul Arya</td><td class="confluenceTd"> 245612345678</td><td class="confluenceTd">Console,   Access Key</td></tr><tr><td class="confluenceTd">company-shared-services</td><td class="confluenceTd">us-ktawsssacct</td><td class="confluenceTd">Shared Services</td><td class="confluenceTd">BPG</td><td class="confluenceTd">300944922012</td><td colspan="1" class="confluenceTd"><br/></td><td class="confluenceTd">No</td><td class="confluenceTd"><span>connected through hub1</span></td><td class="confluenceTd"><a href="https://company-shared-services.signin.aws.amazon.com/console" class="external-link" rel="nofollow">https://company-shared-services.signin.aws.amazon.com/console</a></td><td class="confluenceTd">Rahul Arya</td><td class="confluenceTd">245612345678</td><td class="confluenceTd">Console,   Access Key</td></tr><tr>

<tr><td class="confluenceTd">company-logging</td><td class="confluenceTd">us-ktawslogmonacct</td><td class="confluenceTd">Logging</td><td class="confluenceTd">BPG</td><td class="confluenceTd">542348765123</td><td colspan="1" class="confluenceTd"><br/></td><td class="confluenceTd">No</td><td class="confluenceTd"><span>connected through hub1</span></td><td class="confluenceTd"><a href="https://company-logging.signin.aws.amazon.com/console" class="external-link" rel="nofollow">https://company-logging.signin.aws.amazon.com/console</a></td><td class="confluenceTd">Rahul Arya</td><td class="confluenceTd">800000039768</td><td class="confluenceTd">Console,   Access Key</td></tr><tr><td class="confluenceTd">company-spoke-acct1</td><td class="confluenceTd">us-ktawsspk1acct</td><td class="confluenceTd">Spoke Account</td><td class="confluenceTd">BPG</td><td class="confluenceTd"><span style="text-decoration: none;">103440952267</span></td><td colspan="1" class="confluenceTd"><span style="color: rgb(0,0,0);text-decoration: none;">10.47.8.0/24</span></td><td class="confluenceTd">No</td><td class="confluenceTd"><span>connected through hub1</span></td><td class="confluenceTd"><a href="https://block-chain.signin.aws.amazon.com/console" class="external-link" rel="nofollow">https://block-chain.signin.aws.amazon.com/console</a></td><td class="confluenceTd">Rahul Arya</td><td class="confluenceTd"><p>123456757897</p></td><td class="confluenceTd">Console,   Access Key</td></tr>
```

The problem is that when I scrape the data from the page, the data is run together, and I need to separate the data and insert commas.

How can I insert a comma between each field of the table data so that I can write it to a CSV file?

Comment: It is probably better to parse each `row` (`tr`), extract every element, e.g. `td` and create a `list` of `lists`, which can be read e.g. with `pandas`. Maybe this helps... if not, please post a sample of your data (`page`), so that your output can be reproduced.

Comment: Thanks. I've updated the OP with some sample HTML from the data that I'm trying to extract. I've also put it into [a paste](https://pastebin.com/hEVkWfyX)

Comment: Have a look at Andrej Keselys answer below, I think that is what you need. :-)

Answer (score 1):

For writing the CSV file use built-in `csv` module:

```
data = '''
<table>
<tr>
<td>company-govcloud-ab-mc-stage-admin</td>
<td>company-us-aws-adv-ab-mc-govcloud-admin-stage</td>
<td>Commercial Account</td>
<td>Advisory</td>
<td>12345667890101</td>
<td>No</td>
<td>Island</td>
<td>https://company-govcloud-ab-mc-stage-admin.signin.aws.amazon.com/console</td>
<td>Karel Somebody</td>
<td>123456789101</td>
<td>Console, Access Key</td>
</tr>
</table>'''

headers = ['Company Account Name', 'AWS Account Name', 'Description', 'LOB', 'AWS Account Number', 'Connected to Montvale', 'Peninsula or Island', 'URL', 'Owner', 'Engagement Code', 'CloudOps Access Type']

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')

rows = []
for tr in soup.select('tr'):
    rows.append([td.text for td in soup.select('td')])


with open('out.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=';',
                            quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    writer.writerow(headers)

    for row in rows:
        writer.writerow(row)
```

The file `out.csv` contains:

```
Company Account Name;AWS Account Name;Description;LOB;AWS Account Number;Connected to Montvale;Peninsula or Island;URL;Owner;Engagement Code;CloudOps Access Type
company-govcloud-ab-mc-stage-admin;company-us-aws-adv-ab-mc-govcloud-admin-stage;Commercial Account;Advisory;12345667890101;No;Island;https://company-govcloud-ab-mc-stage-admin.signin.aws.amazon.com/console;Karel Somebody;123456789101;Console, Access Key
```

Screenshot from LibreOffice Calc:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. When I use your code almost exactly as presented it produces [this result](http://www.sharecsv.com/s/d06cd854290a0f365f968574a17af1fb/aws_wiki_page.cs). The only difference between the code that I used and yours is that I am pulling the info from a web page, and I think you are using info embedded into the script. This the [code I'm using](https://pastebin.com/PPdh5FVr]). How can I get the result you show in your post?

Comment: This is the [code](https://pastebin.com/6NjKDtfD) I am using. Sorry, there was a problem with the link I've posted before.

Comment: @bluethundr the CSV seems ok, but the program you are opening it doesn't support ; as delimiter. Try to change it for comma for example. Now I'm on vacation, so I couldn't look at it closely

Comment: Thanks, I am using the comma as the delimeter: `writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)` but I am getting the same result. I am opening the CSV in Excel. And the row data is duplicated 68 times going down. And the unique data is spreading across the page instead of going down.